# How to separate objects within objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data and then add that into cache. I am getting .json file of my node which contain 3 objects in it which i have consoled and shown below.

[image]

now i want to separate out these objects which are present in objects. How can i achieve this ?

Code:

```
fetch('https://hackatonproject8.firebaseio.com/ADS.json')
.then(x => x.json())
.then(x => {
var favData = x;
console.log(x)
```

the last line that is console.log(x) shows an object which is retreived from firebase having 3 objects in it. how can i seperate out each of these objects from the main object.

Comment: It is not very clear the exact output you are after. Can you add a mockup of your data and the desired output.

Comment: I want to seperate out these objects from main objects which i am getting from firebase in result of fetching. Explanation added to question @Akrion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetch('https://hackatonproject8.firebaseio.com/ADS.json')
.then(x => x.json())
.then(x => Object.values(x))
```

Now you have an array of the objects that ware inside that main object x